# ShellCheck integration into posted shell code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

If we could have [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) optionally integrated into shell code blocks, recommended or performed automatically with result output;

It could save a good amount of repetitive and so automatable moderation work, and frustration for both posters and moderators.

- It would provide beginners or inattentive shell coders, means to help themselves fix obvious errors in shell scripts.
- It would inform poster when the pasted shell code contains obvious errors and provide help and related explanation.
- It would encourage posting of syntactically correct and [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- It would promote a good practice of using a linter to check once code.

Examples of posts where a ShellCheck would have provided enough guidance for the poster to help self fix the code:

- [Why doesn't my regex work in my bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763475/7939871) with:

  - [SC2076 Don't quote rhs of =~, it'll match literally rather than as a regex](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2076)
- [BASH: Using a continue in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57758163/7939871) with:

  - [SC1035 You need a space here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1035)
  - [SC2231 Quote expansions in this for loop glob to prevent wordsplitting, e.g. `"$dir"/*.txt` .](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2231)

Comment: I don't think the possible gain here outweighs the added load on the server... Only a small portion of SO's posts would benefit from this library. Ideally, the asker would be using some kind of editor that shows these warnings already, any way.

Comment: Downvotes on feature requests can also mean disagreement with the proposed new feature, not necessarily that the post itself is bad.

Comment: @Cerbrus If ShellCheck could be run Client-Side in JavaScript by [transpiling its Haskell code](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_JavaScript_Problem#Haskell_-.3E_JS), like for the HTML Javascript runable code snippets, would it deal with the server load concern?

Comment: No, as you’d still have to load the library. That was my primary concern. Next to that, you’d have to add extra complexity to a question’s page.

Comment: Also wrt to down votes on feature requests: they also convey the message: *don't implement this*. So a down vote doesn't only mean that it is *inappropriate or of insufficient quality*

Comment: @Cerbrus If "Only a small portion of SO's posts would benefit from this library." doesn't that mean SOs server load would only increase by a small portion? Those of us providing the same "run your code through shellcheck" and references to the same FAQs dozens of times a day would disagree with your statement that "I don't think the possible gain here outweighs the added load on the server" - maybe it'd reduce the load on the server with fewer bad questions and people spending less time doing repetitive work.

Comment: Geez, way to ping someone on a 4-year-old question, @EdMorton... OP is asking for a language-specific library. This means that ___every___ page would need to include a check determining whether or not that language is present, resulting the need for said library. That's an extra action on millions of page loads every day. ___That___ is the extra load I'm worried about. (Other libraries have been rejected for exactly that reason)

Comment: @Cerberus every once in a while the frustration of dealing with this issue overwhelms me and this time around this was the question on meta I could find about it and you were the only person saying it was a bad idea, hence the ping. I don't want to attempt to design a solution as this is far from my area of expertise but I'd have thought this would just be a template loaded for a bash (and a couple of other shells) question. No need to check if a language is present - when the bash tag is clicked load the template. I'd imagine that functionality could be useful in other tags too.

Comment: I forgot I actually requested this feature myself on SE a while back (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372117/361691) - there no-one disagreed but nothing happened. Just frustrating....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow cannot and should not take the place of a suitable IDE for developers.  This includes shell scripts.

Obvious errors should have canonical questions and answers so that questions which are specifically about those can be closed as such.

If the sample code is not reproducible, then closing the question until a time in which it *is* is the only recourse.  We're not here to wait for them to accomplish this task.

Comment: Most shell developers don't use an IDE for several good reasons. Obvious errors have canonical FAQs which shellcheck refers the user to as appropriate.  Questions are frequently not about one such error but about code which contains a multitude of such errors. The issue is not about reproducibility. Every day multiple people post questions which shellcheck could either completely solve for them or could help them get their code to a point where we can quickly see the real issue instead of it being hidden among all the obvious errors.

Comment: @EdMorton then why does that need to be embedded in SO? If those developers are running into problems that shellcheck can fix/point out, why don't they just... Use shellcheck? Sounds like a case of [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).

Comment: @Cerbus clearly it doesn't need to be, but it'd be extremely useful if it was. Many of us don't have and can't install shellcheck (or other tools) for corporate policy reasons and the people posting questions who could use it clearly don't know about it or they'd be using it. So we can say "they should use it" but that's not going to lessen the load on the servers and volunteers of people addressing questions that shellcheck could have handled.

Comment: But again, what's the point? The user should be using the checker _before_ asking a question. He shouldn't be surprised with the output _after_ asking it, that's too late...

Comment: @Cerberus the point is so that either the OP answers their own question just by cleaning up the issues shellcheck tells them about and it never gets posted or that when the questions is posted and we see it all of the issues that shellcheck could detect have already been corrected so we don't need to waste time telling the OP to run shellcheck and/or pointing them to FAQs and/or debugging issues that aren't actually causing whatever problem the OP is asking about. The user should be using the checker while formulating their question, before anyone else sees it.